# SVG not visible in firefox (41.0.2)

Tags: firefox, svg

Greeting to all,

1. This particular svg (background rays) is not displaying in firefox (41.0.2)
   at all, however, the logo, which is an svg too displays correctly. I
   can not figure out the problem. The rays are visible in chrome and
   opera
2. The logo scaling animation is very smooth in chrome but is shaky in
   firefox

DEMO - http://codepen.io/shubhra/full/gavvoM/

DEMO RAYS SVG - http://codepen.io/shubhra/full/jbzPea/

RAYS SVG

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 498.915 500" enable-background="new 0 0 498.915 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="layer1">
    <g id="g3841">

            <radialGradient id="path3768_1_" cx="101464.1797" cy="124353.9453" r="125443.8828" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768" fill="url(#path3768_1_)" d="M-997.83,125.275l2494.575,249.45v-249.45L-997.83,374.725V125.275z"/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-6_1_" cx="101464.8672" cy="124243.2031" r="125540.4063" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-6" fill="url(#path3768-6_1_)" d="M-786.18,956.2l2071.3-1412.4l-160.35-191.1l-1750.6,1794.575L-786.18,956.2z
            "/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-1_1_" cx="101466.7188" cy="124036.9531" r="125413.8672" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-1" fill="url(#path3768-1_1_)" d="M-482.18,1267.825L981.145-767.8l-216.05-124.725L-266.155,1392.55
            L-482.18,1267.825z"/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-16_1_" cx="101466.7188" cy="124036.9531" r="125416.25" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-16" fill="url(#path3768-16_1_)" d="M-89.93,1456.675L588.92-956.7L343.245-1000l-187.5,2500L-89.93,1456.675z"
            />

            <radialGradient id="path3768-9_1_" cx="101466.7188" cy="124036.9531" r="125416.4766" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-9" fill="url(#path3768-9_1_)" d="M343.245,1500l-187.5-2500L-89.93-956.675L588.92,1456.7L343.245,1500z"/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-2_1_" cx="101466.0391" cy="124036.9531" r="125414.2109" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-2" fill="url(#path3768-2_1_)" d="M765.12,1392.55L-266.13-892.55l-216.05,124.725L981.145,1267.8
            L765.12,1392.55z"/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-8_1_" cx="101464.8672" cy="124242.6172" r="125540.3672" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-8" fill="url(#path3768-8_1_)" d="M1124.795,1147.3L-625.83-647.3l-160.35,191.1l2071.3,1412.4L1124.795,1147.3
            z"/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-67_1_" cx="101463.5938" cy="124401.7031" r="125442.0547" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-67" fill="url(#path3768-67_1_)" d="M-965.255,559.4l2429.45-618.775l-85.325-234.4l-2258.8,1087.6
            L-965.255,559.4z"/>

            <radialGradient id="path3768-24_1_" cx="101464.8672" cy="124401.1172" r="125440.6953" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0101 0 0 0.0101 -745.5999 -1013.1006)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1059"/>
            <stop  offset="0.241" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6863"/>
            <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1765"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4618" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.498"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5702" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.1647"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6911" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2471"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path id="path3768-24" fill="url(#path3768-24_1_)" d="M1378.895,793.8L-879.93-293.8l-85.325,234.4l2429.45,618.775
            L1378.895,793.8z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please can you create a minimal testcase.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson, I have provided a demo link above my code. Is something else required as well?

Comment: Cut it down to a few lines that demonstrate the issue ie. a [mcve]. One gradient, one shape etc.

Comment: The codepen displays in FF 41.0.2 for me.  The animation is a bit broken. I expect that is due to your use of `transform-origin` with percentages - which AFAIK is still broken in FF for SVG elements.  But I think that is fixed in the current nightlies. Robert will know more about that.

Comment: I have updated my question with a minimal demo (DEMO RAYS SVG). It only has sunburst svg code and a few lines of css. I still can't see the sunburst svg in firefox. I only see the blue background

Comment: @PaulLeBeau https://longsonr.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/transform-origin-for-svg-elements/ There is a dispute over transform-box though, Chrome have not implemented it per specification and want to change the specification. That makes specifying transform-origin without also specifying transform-box (and setting the Firefox pref) appear different in Chrome vs Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS has this in it.

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, circle cover, #022C4B 0%, #00252b 80%);
background-image: radial-gradient(top, circle cover,  #022C4B 0%, #00252b 80%);
```

Early drafts of the specification allowed cover as a keyword but the w3c keyword is now farthest-corner (although this is the default and can be omitted) so I think what you want is something like this...

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top, #022C4B 0%, #00252b 80%);
```

If you look in the Firefox browser console you'll see that there are warnings that it cannot interpret the radial-gradient.

More details on the syntax can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. this is what I see in chrome - http://imgur.com/GyL60xO and this is what i see in firefox - http://imgur.com/YJlHVY9

Comment: My Firefox (41.0.2) displays the same as your Chrome screenshot.

Comment: That's strange. What might be the problem?